# 5th string needed from combination

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

Suppose there is a `string s=abcd`

I want the 5th string consisting of `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`, which is `adbc`. 
But I also get all the answers beyond it which I don't need.

So how can I stop this method after its 5th execution?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test{
   long times;
   int n=1;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test tm=new Test();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        while(t!=0){
            String s=in.nextLine();
            char ch[]=s.toCharArray();          
            Arrays.sort(ch);
            String sort=String.valueOf(ch);            
            String ans;
            long n=Long.parseLong(in.nextLine());
            tm.times=n;
            tm.permu("",sort);
            t--;           
        }
    }

    private void permu(String prefix,String str) {
        int len=str.length();          

        if(len==0){
            if(n==times){
                System.out.println(prefix);
            }
            else{
                n++;
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                permu(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, len));
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Secondly is there any site where I can read about permutation, combination and probability for calculating and finding the permutation, combination and probability... For coding thing not for mathematical thing..i.e I know how to solve mathematically but I can't code it.. Unable to write logic for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't change `n` after running the check and printing a result in your recursion. That's why you print everything after `adbc`.

If you use this code when checking:

```
if (n == times) {
    System.out.println(prefix);
    n = -1;
} else {
    if (n > -1)
        n++;
}
```

then you only get `n == times` to be true once, and that's when the `prefix` is `adbc`.

Example test for the solution:

[image: output]

If you want to stop a method that has no return value (has `void` in its return type in the method signature), then calling `return;` will exit the method... But it isn't needed here.

Comment: @ Itamar Green:thanks..
and is there any built in library function to stop a method..like the above one something like System.exit() though it will stop the whole execution..something like that..

and any link for the 2nd question???

Comment: @Fawkes (firstly, nice name) It is considered off topic both to ask two distinct questions in one question, and also to ask for off-site resources... So I didn't answer that part. However I don't see why you need to stop the method, because it's working.

Comment: @ Itamar Green (thanks): i didnt know about "two distinct question " thing.
the question came from coding competiton  thats why i have to stop at 5th execution.there is one another question which iam stuck for 6 months combinatroics problem.thats why i asked about reference material.

Comment: @Fawkes well, now you know. Very happy to help :P